# margin not overlap when the outer explicit set height

Tags: html, css

I wonder why the phenomenon will happen?

the inner div set margin-bottom 16px

As far as I know,the outer div contact with the inner div,no padding or border,if the outer div isn't set height css style,the under div will 16px away from the outer div, because the margin is overlap.However,if height css style is set on the outer div,the under div is close to the outer div.

so,can you explain how this phenomenon is caused?

```css
.outer {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}

.inner {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.under {
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="under"></div>
```

Comment: You forgot to include the CSS in your question. (I'm assuming you included the HTML only because the site wouldn't let you post just the CodePen link - there's a very good reason for that.)

Comment: The child element's margin will not affect its parent element's siblings.

Comment: if you remove height css style on the outer div,you will find the under div is move down @TylerRoper

Comment: You guessed it @BoltClock,: )

Comment: @HanQ *"if you remove height css style on the outer div, you will find the under div is move down"* - Ah, well now you've touched on something interesting. I've explained this below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first things first, let's address this:

> if you remove height css style on the outer div,you will find the under div is move down

This is due to [Margin Collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing):

> If there is no border, padding, inline part, block formatting context created, or clearance to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. **The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.**
>
> These rules apply even to margins that are zero, so the margin of a first/last child ends up outside its parent (according to the rules above) whether or not the parent's margin is zero.

Your child margin is collapsing with the parent margin, thus the 16px margin acts as part of the parent.

---

However **by specifying a `height`, you negate margin collapsing**.

From the [W3 Box Model spec*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties):

> Two margins are *adjoining* if and only if:
>
> - Both belong to vertically-adjacent box edges, i.e. form one of the following pairs:
>
>   - The bottom margin of a last in-flow child and bottom margin of its parent **if the parent has 'auto' computed height**

Because the margins do not collapse, the child's margin will simply attempt to expand the height of the outer div (which won't be reflected, because the parent has a strictly set height of `100px`).

---

**But wait**... what if we broke the collapse *some other way?* Would we see the height increase by `16px`?

> Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
>
> - no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them

Seems easy enough. Let's add a border to break this rule.

```css
.outer {
  background: yellow;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.under {
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="under"></div>
```

Voila! As expected, the margins *do not collapse*, therefore the child's margin attempts to expand the height of the parent. With no `height` property on the parent to counter this, the height of the parent *grows to `116px`*.

---

<sup>* This is pointing at an older spec, however this behavior has not changed. In fact, some of the newer spec documents I've found reference/link to this one.</sup>

Comment: Thanks,Very well explained,and very interesting

Answer (score 1):

`inner` is nested inside `outer`, and `under` is directly underneath `outer` with no space or padding. So regardless of the margin given to `inner`, there'll be no space between `outer` and `under`.

You can do this by simply adding a `margin-top` to `under`.

```
.outer{
    background:yellow;
    height:100px;
}

.inner{
    height:100px;
    background:green;
}

.under{
  background:red;
  height:10px;
  margin-top:16px;
}
```

Comment: That is not entirely true. If I take out the `height: 100px` from `.outer`, the margin between `outer` and `under` shows

Comment: Ah, I see that. I think this is due to the `height: 100px` assigned to `.inner`, not the `margin` setting.

Comment: @zer0 Yes,I actually want to know why adding height to the outer div causes inconsistent behavior

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a margin to child element to affect on a parent element. You may add `margin-bottom:16px;` to Outer class as below

```
.outer{
background:yellow;
height:100px;
margin-bottom:16px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry,that is not i want answer.The answer, I hope, is to explain the performance.

Answer (score 1):

set .outer `height:auto;`

```css
.outer{
  background:yellow;
  height:auto;
}
.inner{
  height:100px;
  background:green;
  margin-bottom:16px;
}
.under{
  background:red;
  height:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="under"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry,that is not i want answer @Sooriya Dasanayake